# android: how can I verify, that device support multitouch?

Tags: android, multi-touch

How can I verify, that device support multitouch event? If device have resistent display, multitouch is not possible. Is that way to find out, what kind of display is in device, or if device support multitouch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need multitouch, include:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
```

in your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html). Your application will not be listed in the Market for devices that lack multitouch.

If you wish to conditionally support multitouch, use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()` to see if `android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch` is available.

Comment: How common is it nowadays for an android not to support multi-touch?

Comment: @SSHThis: Google TV doesn't. There are also varying levels of multitouch (e.g., "jazzhands" for supporting 10 simultaneous touches), for those apps with specific needs (e.g., piano keyboard simulators).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your answer helped me greatly

Answer (score 11):

A quick example:

```
boolean multi = 
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PackageManager.hasSystemFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) with [PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)

There is an [interesting series of articles on Android multi-touch](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content) that are worth a look

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Answer (score 1):

```
public final String SUPPORT = "Supported";
public final String NOT_SUPPORT = "None";

if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH)) {
            aDisplayInfo.multiTouch = SUPPORT;
        } else {
            aDisplayInfo.multiTouch = NOT_SUPPORT;
        }
```