# Android: Check if device has Touch support

Tags: android, android-hardware

Is there any way to check if an Android device (phone) has Touchscreen support or not?

So if device has touchscreen I can fire a method where the user can choose something via touch, and if not then he can choose via hardware button input...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5585043/599993

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen");
```

but that's been [stated to not always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335707/determine-if-the-device-has-touch-screen-or-not), specifically when a device is connected to a tv or other screen through hdmi, since it deals with the android player itself and not the connected device, but it should work for your needs.

Comment: As long as you rely on the device itself it works, it cannot detect external displays which is pretty obvious.